# exclude an asset regex

Tags: regex-greedy

I need to write a regex that will capture everything in a directory except one asset.
Ex.
I want to exclude `/test1/test2/new.jpg` and capture everything else in `/test1/test2/`

I tried the negative lookahead but doesn't seem to work.

`/test1/test2/^(?!new.jpg).*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `^` in between:

```
/test1/test2/(?!new.jpg).*
```

See this: https://regex101.com/r/uHgBZc/1

Comment: That did it. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Please also consider picking this as the answer to your question.